# how to use AND with in_array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please refer below code:

```
foreach(range(1,12) as $i)
{
   if (!in_array($i,$maintain_month) AND $pay->status=='failure'){
       $pmoth = date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$i,1));
       $month=date('m');
       echo $pmoth;
    }
}
```

I want to check status in if condition.i.e. if the month is not in array as well if the status of month is failure.

when i put such a if condition ,that condition is not working.please help me to get it.

Comment: You won't work how? What values do you check?

Comment: nothin wrong with the code, you should check for $maintain_month be  an array and $pay->status is defined to check echo $i in the else part

Comment: code is working see - https://3v4l.org/NXUIL , check `$maintain_month` array or `$pay->status` value